# Error while executing SSIS package which contains Script component through SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have written one SSIS 2012 package which is fetching records from CSV and put it into staging DB and from staging DB , using SSIS script component task, I am inserting data into Dynamics CRM. So far it is working fine when I manually execute SSIS package.

but when I run the SSIS package using SQL server agent job, I encounter below error. After seeing below error at step "Insert TLM Headers Script Component " I understand that it is failing at script component which I have used in SSIS package, but I am not sure what is the cause behind that? please advise.

Error:

Executed as user: domain\user account. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5556.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  1:21:41 PM  Error: 2015-02-25 13:21:45.94     Code: 0xC0047062     Source: Insert TLM Headers Script Component [205]     Description: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID, IDTSBuffer100 pDTSBuffer, IntPtr bufferWirePacket)  End Error  Error: 2015-02-25 13:21:45.94     Code: 0xC0047022     Source: Insert TLM Headers SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Script Component" (205) failed with error code 0x80131501 while processing input "Input 0" (215). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  1:21:41 PM  Finished: 1:21:45 PM  Elapsed:  4.009 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: Have you tried to follow the suggestion in the error to either: **(1)** turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or **(2)** turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Comment: What does the script do? Smells like it's talking to a web service. Does that service require authentication and if so, does the account that is executing the package have permissions? Does it expect a wsdl at some location there isn't one? Did the devs create a custom DLL that needs installed on the server? Has this ever worked on the machine in question? Does it work anywhere?